# c++ iterator operation do not check overflow?

Tags: c++

Once I wrote a line:

```
while(++itr!=container.end()) 
{
   do something here
}
```

Even after itr passed end(), the condition is still true. I am puzzled. I thought operator++ should check boundaries. But it seems not. Here is a test program:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> x;
    vector<string> y;
    x.push_back(10);
    y.push_back("test");
    auto itr = x.end();
    assert(itr == x.end());
    // this line makes itr past end
    ++itr;
    // this line is true
    assert(itr != x.end());
    // this line doesn't report any address issue or segment fault
    cout << *itr << endl;
    auto itry = y.end();
    assert(itry == y.end());
    ++itry;
    //  no error report
    assert(itry != y.end());
    //  report segment fault
    cout << *itry << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it true that iterator in std c++ do not check past end or before begin() for -- operator?

Comment: C++ is all about not paying for what you don't need.  Iterators do not perform bounds checking, that's your job.

Comment: Well, `end() + 1` is not the same as `end()`. Why would you expect `!=` to return true?

Answer (score 4):

This is how they work and this is for a performance reason. Iterators are modeled after pointers, pointer don't check for boundaries on increment.

You will get undefined behavior though if you increment past `end()`.

Comment: Might?  Here there be nasal demons.

Comment: Will is most probably the right word although we sometimes get lucky with what's in memory at a particular moment.

Comment: when will you _not_ get UB? the result may looks valid but it still UB

Comment: @EricFortin: When that happens it's downright *unlucky*.  You would much prefer a crash so that you can fix your bug.  The alternative is to push your buggy program into production only to have it blow up some time down the road (and it will). UB doesn't mean "this is only bad if it doesn't work".  This is always UB, regardless of what happens.

Comment: @EdS Totally agree, I prefer a crash. So yes it would better worded as unlucky depending from which end you look at it ;)

Comment: Edited to specify that it is undefined behavior even if in some circumstances it might not manifest itself right on the spot.

Comment: Implementations are explicitly granted freedom to handle Undefined Behaviour by "behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment", so while you "will" get undefined behaviour at a C++ Standard level, you "might" get defined behaviour at an environment level.  At best, it will be non-portable and subject to the whims of your environment maintainers.

Comment: UB does not mean "crash".  It does not mean "corrupt memory".  It means "anything can happen, and anything can cause it to do something different".  The nasal demons will wait in the shadows, and attack at the worst moment.  And yes, sometimes UB is defined by your implementation: but I have yet to see a compiler document what happens when you increment a pointer past the end of a container.

Answer (score 0):

yep.

```
    while(++itr!=container.end()) 
    {
       do something here
    }
if itr==end() ,++itr can be anything!
so,you must write :
    if(it != xxx.end())
    {
        while(++it != xxx.end())
        {
             do sth
        }
    }
```